# What does the callstack look like with promises and async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callstack, event-loop

I recently watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ and am trying to find a similar explanation for with Promises. Specifically in node.

I'm probably wrong but I'm under the impression that Promises are placed on a microtask queue, the microtask queue is only processed when the callstack is empty and once the event-loop starts processing the microtask queue, it processes it until the queue is empty.

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => {
  setTimeout(res, ms)
});

const doTask1 = (workerId) => sleep(1000).then(() => console.log(`[${workerId}] Completed Task 1`));
const doTask2 = (workerId) => sleep(5000).then(() => console.log(`[${workerId}] Completed Task 2`));

const worker = async (workerId) => {
  console.log(`[${workerId}] Starting work`)
  await doTask1(workerId);
  await doTask2(workerId);
  console.log(`[${workerId}] Completed all tasks`);
};

worker('A');
worker('B');
```

When the snippet above is run, both worker A and B will start Task 1 and 2 at around the same time and complete at around the same time. I'm having trouble consolidating that behavior with what I've read/seen about Promises/microtasks and event-loops.

I imagine that when the code executes, the call stack looks like:

1. Callstack: [main.js]
2. Callstack: [main.js][worker('A')]
3. Callstack: [main.js][worker('A')][console.log()]
4. Callstack: [main.js][worker('A')][await doTask1()]

When we use `await`, what happens to the callstack? I suppose this is related to how generators work?

6. Callstack: ?? | Microtask Queue: [doTask1()]

<strike>What does it mean for the event-loop to "process" the microtask queue? Does processing `doTask1()` mean the event-loop is waiting 1 second? That doesn't sound right. Is the 1 second wait being done on a different thread (is that the right term?) as shown in the Youtube video's depiction of WebAPIs? Once the timeout is complete, the Promise's `res` goes onto the message queue where the event loop eventually picks it up and resolves the Promise? Does the callstack have to be empty for the callstack to execute `res`?</strike>

I'm stuck at this point and not sure what happens next in the callstack, the message queue, the microtask queue and how the event-loop decides what to do next.

Comment: First of all, `await` is applied to the promise that `dotask1()` returned, *after* that call - the call stack of `sleep`, `setTimeout`, and `then` is normal before `await` comes into consideration.

Comment: Yes, `await` works similar to a `yield` in generators - so the call stack returns from the `async function` call with a promise value. Then `main` continues to call `worker('B')` etc until all synchronous code has finished executing - that's when the microtask and event queues are entered.

Comment: **run your code here see the behaviour of eventloop** 
 [http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D]

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari Getting error when running