# How is async/await working in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am reading MDN on how async code works with javascript. They propose this example:

```
async function myFetch() {
  let response = await fetch('coffee.jpg');

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }

  let myBlob = await response.blob();

  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = objectURL;
  document.body.appendChild(image);
}

myFetch()
.catch(e => {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + e.message);
});
```

Function myFetch() is defined and then it's called in a Promise-way style. How exactly is the function executed? It's an async function, so I assume that it's given to some thread to execute without interfering with the single thread that runs Javascript code?
Also in the docs they said await is stoping the code on that line until completion? So the function can't be executed by the main application thread because then it's not async code anymore?
So those are my issues and I wanna be sure I understand this mechanism before I start writing actual code. Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5 will probably explain a lot of what you're wondering about

Comment: [JavaScript Event Loop And Call Stack Explained](https://felixgerschau.com/javascript-event-loop-call-stack/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using async/await is pretty similar to using promises, async function returns a Promise for you, that promise can have one of three statuses (Pending, Fulfilled, Rejected)

By default, the returned Promise is Fulfilled (Resolved)
similar to:

```
Promise.resolve().then(_ => { //... })
```

using await, the Promise will be pending on the code that you are awaiting for

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // ... some tasks here
  resolve(resolvedData);
})
.then(_ => { //... })
```

when an error is thrown, automatically or manually, the Promise will be rejected

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject(); // Reject manually
})
.then(_ => { })
.catch(e => { //... })
```

By default, all JavaScript code is executing within the main thread, which is the only thread that JavaScript has

Look at the following example:

```
async function c() {
    const t = await Array.from(Array(100000000).keys())
}
c().then(t => console.log('I am waiting for the Promise to be fulfilled!'))
console.log('Hey, I don\'t need to wait');
```

You will get the expected output:

```
"Hey, I don't need to wait"
"I am waiting for the Promise to be fulfilled!"
```

but both logs are waiting for filling this `100000000` array, so the main thread now is busy and blocked to complete this task first, JavaScript itself can't help with this case,

Another Example:

```
async function c() {
    const t = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
}
c().then(_ => console.log('I am waiting for the Promise to be fulfilled!'))
console.log('Hey, I don\'t need to wait');
```

Here you'll get the same result, but `Hey, I don't need to wait` will be logged immediately, and only `I am waiting for the Promise to be fulfilled!` will be waiting,

Why? here we need to refer to few important things to read more about (Event Loop, Call Stack, Micro & Macro tasks )

In simple words, the promise behaves the same, it's pending on something, and the first console log in the code is awaiting the promise to be fulfilled,

the difference is that the task that we are waiting for to have a fulfilled promise now is not thread-blocking, it is not controlled by JavaScript itself

the fetching task is managed by an external API that is observed by the Event loop, in this case, the call stack will not be busy, and the main JavaScript thread can continue working, the code that will resolve the promise is added to a queue and will be pushed to the call stack by the Event loop when the fetching task is done by the external API

Comment: So I should use await only with modern APIs while doing I/O? So then the await fetch will block the code at that line and then the main is going in another example to execute more code?

Comment: I try to write a Node js backend, so all of this is important to me because I want my server to be as responsive as possible and using an await somewhere I shouldnt would give me some bad performance I think

Answer (score 1):

> Function myFetch() is defined and then it's called in a Promise-way style.

It's called like any other function. All `async` functions wrap the return value in a Promise, thus there are `then`, `catch` and `finally` methods available.

> How exactly is the function executed?

Using `()` like any other function.

> It's an async function, so I assume that it's given to some thread to execute without interfering with the single thread that runs Javascript code?

There is no need to have it run on some other thread. As you say, JavaScript execution happens in a single thread.

> Also in the docs they said await is stoping the code on that line until completion?

Yes, in that async function.

> So the function can't be executed by the main application thread because then it's not async code anymore?

There doesn't have to be any threading involved. It is only the `fetch` and `blob` operations that are performed asynchronously. While those operations are being awaited, the event loop and the execution of code outside the async function will continue. If you have code below the call to `myFetch` then that will be executed while the `fetch` is being awaited, unless you await the call to `myFetch` itself.

`async` and `await` are syntactic sugar on top of Promises, so effectively your code is doing the following:

```js
fetch('coffee.jpg').then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
  }
  response.blob().then(myBlob => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = objectURL;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
  });
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + e.message);
});
```

Comment: See [Does a async function gets added to the callstack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673771/does-a-async-function-gets-added-to-the-callstack) and [Working of call stack when async/await is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241258/working-of-call-stack-when-async-await-is-used) and [What does the callstack look like with promises and async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105842/what-does-the-callstack-look-like-with-promises-and-async-await) etc.

Comment: "There doesn't have to be any threading involved. It is only the fetch and blob operations that are performed asynchronously. While those operations are being awaited, the event loop and the execution of code outside the async function will continue" - how can this two coexist? You have no threading, so the main thread executes the I/O so then how can it still go in another parts of the code and execute more code?

Comment: Still have to see the links you sent me, thanks!

Comment: A browser, for example, can make a system call for the I/O then continue with JavaScript execution while it waits for the result from the operating system.

Comment: Ok so it still some thread involved, just it's not controlled by your code? I mean the browser worker? I dont know about the browser side to much, I use this codebase in building a backend with node and I want good performances, that's why I ask those blocking/non-blocking questions